# Geting an error in Pycharm using TensorFlow "WARNING:tensorflow:Output dense_1 missing from loss dictionary"

Tags: python, tensorflow, pycharm

I am using PyCharm, and I am just getting into Neural Networks.

I am trying to use TensorFlow 2.0,enter code here my system is 64bit.

I am folowing this tutorial (https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/classification) on the TensorFlow website.

And when I run the program, I get this error:

*

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Output dense_1 missing from loss dictionary. We assume this was done on purpose. The fit and evaluate APIs will not be expecting any data to be passed to dense_1.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/PycharmProjects/NN_TensorFlow/NN_TensorFlow.py", line 52, in <module>
    metrics=['accuracy'])
  File "E:\PycharmProjects\NN_TensorFlow\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\training\tracking\base.py", line 457, in _method_wrapper
    result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\PycharmProjects\NN_TensorFlow\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 373, in compile
    self._compile_weights_loss_and_weighted_metrics()
  File "E:\PycharmProjects\NN_TensorFlow\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\training\tracking\base.py", line 457, in _method_wrapper
    result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\PycharmProjects\NN_TensorFlow\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 1653, in _compile_weights_loss_and_weighted_metrics
    self.total_loss = self._prepare_total_loss(masks)
  File "E:\PycharmProjects\NN_TensorFlow\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 1752, in _prepare_total_loss
    raise ValueError('The model cannot be compiled '
ValueError: The model cannot be compiled because it has no loss to optimize.
```

*

Does anyone have any idea what is wrong?

My code:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals

# TensorFlow and tf.keras
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

# Helper libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

print(tf.__version__)

# Load data set that exists in keras. There are a lot of data sets in keras
data = keras.datasets.fashion_mnist

# split into testing and training data
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = data.load_data()

# asign a string to the number of the "lables".
class_names = ['T-shirt/top', 'Trouser', 'Pullover', 'Dress', 'Coat',
               'Sandal', 'Shirt', 'Sneaker', 'Bag', 'Ankle boot']

# shrink the data. default color range is 0 - 255, we shrink it down to 0 - 1
train_images = train_images/255.0
test_images = test_images/255.0

# show training image, cmap=plt.cm.binary -> show image properly
#plt.imshow(train_images[7], cmap=plt.cm.binary)
#plt.show()

# Neural network model, Define architecture of the model, SEQUENTIAL means you define the layers in order
model = keras.Sequential([
    # INPUT LAYER FLATTEN
    # meaning the data is compressed in to an array of 784
    # instead of 28x28 matrix (matrix because its a 28 pixel x 28pixel image)
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28,28)),
    # HIDDEN LAYER DENSE
    # meaning that every neuron is connected to every other neuron
    # Activation function = rectify linear unit (very fast function),
    # Activation function is arbitrary, meaning we can pick different ones
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu"),
    # OUTPUT LAYER DENSE
    # activation function = softmax (turning output values into 0 - 1)
    keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax")
])

# COMPILE OPTIMIZER "adam" (standard optimizer for such stuff)
# LOSS FUNCTION "sparse_categorical_crossentropy" (very fameus function - look up ONLINE), Arbitrary
# METRICS "accuracy" (what we are looking at, what do we want to do), we want to lower Loss function
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              Loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])


model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=5)  # EPOCHS, how many times the computer seas the same image
# having a higher EPOCHS doesn't necessary mean a higher accuracy

test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(test_images,  test_labels, verbose=2)

print("Tested Acc: ", test_acc)
```

Comment: The keyword in `compile` is `loss`, not `Loss`.

Comment: omg thank you. I feel soo stupid. I literaly tryed everything else.